# Error while trying to get max number from SQL database using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database running with username, password and user_id as primary key
and I'm trying to get the highest number out of the `user_id` column using eloquent.

This is my current error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 2 limit 1)

This is what my model looks like:

users.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


use DB;
use Eloquent;

class users extends Eloquent
{
  public static function register()
  {
      $user_id = users::find(DB::table('users')->max('user_id'));


return $user_id;
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Laravel considers the primary key name is `id`. You must declare your primary key name if it's not `id`. So, add this in your user class:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

Here is how the whole class should look:

```
class users extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    public static function register()
    {
        $user_id = users::find(DB::table('users')->max('user_id'));
        return $user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: the error changed into SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`, `user_id`) values (adw, awd, {"username":"","password":"","user_id":2}))

Answer (score 0):

Get the highest user like this

```
$user = users::orderBy('user_id', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the query I gave you. What is causing this error you just showed me?